# Select statement with count and without

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL statement to select data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT count(table.data) as cntd, table.datatwo
FROM table LEFT JOIN tabletwo ON table.id=tabletwo.tableid
WHERE tabletwo.dated='2016-11-17' AND table.datafive='1'
```

If I keep it the way above - it returns the data as below:

```
cntd datatwo
4    92
```

However the correct data should be:

```
cntd datatwo
2   92
2   93
```

As there are two different `datatwo`. When I select the statement without cont - it shows both `datatwo`.

```
datatwo
92
93
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: i hope these are not the real table and column names !

Comment: @Crozet why would think that? It's valid. You talking about the word `table`? I can see the `FROM table` failing if it were though, not the others but I doubt that's what they're really using. Might only be representative.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'm talking about the non descriptive table and column names

Comment: @Crozet ah ok. Yeah, I can see why you said that now.

Comment: @Crozet Seems I was right about the table/column names being only descriptive ;-) as per [OP's comment below...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639400/select-statement-with-count-and-without#comment68511528_40639569) *"The naming of table is not what is in the table - it is in other language than english - so for sake of this question i used some other names."* - as per my *"Might only be representative."* ;-) Just saying. Must've been my Spidey sense tingling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite how random and unintuitive your table naming is, it appears what you want is to use a `GROUP BY` statement:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT count(table.data) as cntd,
    table.datatwo
FROM table
LEFT JOIN tabletwo ON table.id=tabletwo.tableid
WHERE tabletwo.dated='2016-11-17'
  AND table.datafive='1'
GROUP BY tabletwo.tableid
```

The `COUNT` statement is an *aggregate* function so it causes the rows to collapse down to one. Grouping by the unique value for each row will cause it to aggregate in groups.

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what I was missing (yet so obvious). The naming of table is not what is  in the table - it is in other language than english - so for sake of this question i used some other names. But will keep in mind to try to use better examples next time.